# Ollydump unable to read memory of debugged process

Tags: debugging, reverse-engineering

I try to unpack UPX 3.91 Pack. Now I reach to OEP but when I try to dump the debugged process with ollydump plugin I got the error "unable to read memory of debugged process"

why is that ?

Comment: Are you using any other plugins?

Comment: Yes you think this is the problem?

Comment: I seem to recall something about the "Olly Advanced" plugin and its "Anti-Anti Hardware Breakpoint" setting. Did you have that plugin and feature enabled?

Comment: I seem to have this issue after creating a memory breakpoint.  I think it's a bug.

Comment: how did you solve this?

Comment: i think i used some unpacker which do that but its was a long time ago so i'm not sure